# Need a default choice selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on website and i have this code:

http://liveweave.com/KDPgcO

It shows a menu that displays some content when a url is clicked, That is what i want but the only thing is that i need that one choice is selected or displayed by default:

So when the page loads that javascript must show the first choice on the menu by default.

the code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="pages_about" class="textContainer_about">


  <div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
 <img src="../images/fondo1.png" alt="" height="" width="800"/> 
 </div>


  <div class="textWord_about" data-link="second">
 <img src="../images/fondo2.png" alt="" height="" width="800"/> 
</div>

  <div class="textWord_about" data-link="third">
 <img src="../images/fondo3.png" alt="" height="" width="800"/> 
</div>


 <div class="textWord_about" data-link="fourth">
 <img src="../images/fondo4.png" alt="" height="" width="800"/> 
</div>
<CENTER>
<div id="menu_about">   
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="first"><img src="../images/edif.png" alt="" height="" width="65"/></a>
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="second"><img src="../images/admininver.png" alt="" height="" width="65"/></a>
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="third"><img src="../images/finan.png" alt="" height="" width="60"/></a>
<a class="link" href="#about" data-link="fourth"><img src="../images/inmo.png" alt="" height="" width="60"/></a> 
</div>
</CENTER>
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any comments that you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to fire the action for the first link on the start of the page? It is not a 100% clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger click on the first link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.textWord_about').hide();

$('.link').click(function() {
    $('.textWord_about').hide();       
    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('link') + ']').fadeIn({
        width: '200px'
    }, 300);
}).first().trigger('click');

</script>
```

Comment: could even shorten it to `$('.link').click(function() { /* ... */ }).first().trigger('click');`